# Using PHP, how can I read a server's error page?

Tags: php, function

I want to read a server's reply for a certain request, modify it to my needs, and send it to the site visitor. get_headers() works perfectly for the headers, but if the requested file is missing (404), and that's exactly what I want to use, get_file_contents(), readfile() and other functions I've tried all break with the warning/error that the file is missing instead of reading the replied stream into a variable.

So what I want is a function similar to get_headers() only for the rest of the data, like a get_data() that doesn't cancel. Is there such a thing?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Does your PHP send requests to a third-party site, or do you expect PHP to intercept errors generated by your own web server?

Comment: Have you tried using the [HTTPRequest](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.httprequest.php) class?

Comment: I want the error file from "my own" server, but the solution to be flexible so that it works anywhere. I thought I'd just forward the headers exactly as they are, replace the missing file name with the current script name (if the error file is some kind of message - could be anything, really) and pretend that the requested file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `curl_exec`. It will always return the body unless the `CURLOPT_FAILONERROR` option is set to `TRUE`.

Here's an example:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/thisrequestwillerror';

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

// This is the default, but just making sure...
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);

// Execute and return as a string
$str = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

// Dump the response body
var_dump($str);
```

Wrap this in a function and use it wherever you need to get an HTTP response body in your application.

Comment: Thanks. See, the thing is that I don't have the curl module installed, and I'm not sure that the my future web hotel will have it either. I was hoping for a solution (just like get_headers()) that works independently.